# Get Results View from ICollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to get the "Results View" from the ICollectionView? If so, how?

I don't want the "SourceCollection" but instead the "Results View".

Thanks for help!

Comment: Isn't the ICollectionView itself the "Results View"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to evaluate the results of the filtering programatically:

1. Check if there are any results:

   ```
   yourCollectionViewSource.View.IsEmpty
   ```
2. Get a list of the filtered results:

   ```
   yourCollectionViewSource.View.OfType().ToList()
   ```
3. Get count of how many items are in the results:

   ```
   yourCollectionViewSource.View.OfType().Count()
   ```

*.OfType*  is a Linq Extension method, so be sure to add Link to your Using statements.

Once you get the OfType result you can then use Linq to do any additional queries.